# mysql query INSERT INTO and SET problems

Tags: php, mysql, insert, set

I've been scratching my head for a good hour or so now, but I can't figure out what I have done wrong here. I hope someone can point me in the correct direction.

I am trying to insert some data into an SQL database using the INSERT INTO method, but it just doesn't seem to work. I included lots of echos to see try and see where exactly the error could be. From this I know that the code is OK up until the INSERT INTO part is called. Also, checking the database online revelas that no information is added... The online database has 3 tables, 'noise', 'wave', and 'pulse'. Also, all of the fields are present, so I really can't understand why this code is failing.

```
<?php
//Connect To Database
$hostname='myhostname';
$username='myusername';
$password='mypassword';
$dbname='dbname';
mysql_connect($hostname,$username, $password) OR DIE ('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.');
mysql_select_db($dbname);

// test to see what kind of instrument is being uploaded.

$type=strip_tags($_GET['TYPE']);

if($type == 'noise') {
    $audio=strip_tags($_GET['AUDIO']); 
    echo $audio;
    $automate=strip_tags($_GET['AUTOMATE']);
    echo $automate;
    $by=strip_tags($_GET['BY']);
    echo $by;
    $envelope=strip_tags($_GET['ENVELOPE']);
    echo $envelope;
    $length=strip_tags($_GET['LENGTH']);
    echo $length;
    $name=strip_tags($_GET['NAME']);
    echo $name;
    $notes=strip_tags($_GET['NOTES']);
    echo $notes;
    $output=strip_tags($_GET['OUTPUT']);
    echo $output;
    $patchname=strip_tags($_GET['PATCH_NAME']);
    echo $patchname;
    $s_cmd=strip_tags($_GET['S_CMD']);
    echo $s_cmd;
    $shape=strip_tags($_GET['SHAPE']);
    echo $shape;
    $table=strip_tags($_GET['TABLE']);
    echo $table;
    $table0=strip_tags($_GET['table0']);
    echo $table0;
    $table1=strip_tags($_GET['table1']);
    echo $table1;
    $table2=strip_tags($_GET['table2']);
    echo $table2;
    $table3=strip_tags($_GET['table3']);
    echo $table3;
    $table4=strip_tags($_GET['table4']);
    echo $table4;
    $table5=strip_tags($_GET['table5']);
    echo $table5;
    $table6=strip_tags($_GET['table6']);
    echo $table6;
    $table7=strip_tags($_GET['table7']);
    echo $table7;
    $table8=strip_tags($_GET['table8']);
    echo $table8;
    $table9=strip_tags($_GET['table9']);
    echo $table9;
    $tableA=strip_tags($_GET['tableA']);
    echo $tableA;
    $tableB=strip_tags($_GET['tableB']);
    echo $tableB;
    $tableC=strip_tags($_GET['tableC']);
    echo $tableC;
    $tableD=strip_tags($_GET['tableD']);
    echo $tableD;
    $tableE=strip_tags($_GET['tableE']);
    echo $tableE;
    $tableF=strip_tags($_GET['tableF']);
    echo $tableF;

    //input this info into the SQL noise instrument table
    $request = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `noise` SET
        AUDIO = '$audio', 
        AUTOMATE = '$automate', 
        BY = '$by', 
        ENVELOPE = '$envelope', 
        LENGTH = '$length', 
        NAME ='$name', 
        NOTES = '$notes', 
        OUTPUT = '$output', 
        PATCH_NAME = '$patchname', 
        S_CMD = '$s_cmd', 
        SHAPE = '$shape', 
        TABLE = '$table', 
        table0 = '$table0', 
        table1 = '$table1', 
        table2 = '$table2', 
        table3 = '$table3', 
        table4 = '$table4',
        table5 = '$table5', 
        table6 = '$table6', 
        table7 = '$table7', 
        table8 = '$table8', 
        table9 = '$table9', 
        tableA = '$tableA', 
        tableB = '$tableB', 
        tableC = '$tableC', 
        tableD = '$tableD', 
        tableE = '$tableE',
        tableF = '$tableF',
        TYPE = '$type';" );
if($request) {
    echo "Your patch has been successfully uploaded.";
    echo "Thanks for contributing!";
}
else {
    echo "there has been a problem";
    }
}
?>
```

When I load this URL from my iPhone app:

```
NSString *website = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://mywebsite/problem.php?AUDIO=%@&AUTOMATE=%@&BY=%@&ENVELOPE=%@&LENGTH=%@&NAME=%@&NOTES=%@&OUTPUT=%@&PATCH_NAME=%@&S_CMD=%@&SHAPE=%@&TABLE=%@&table0=%@&table1=%@&table2=%@&table3=%@&table4=%@&table5=%@&table6=%@&table7=%@&table8=%@&table9=%@&tableA=%@&tableB=%@&tableC=%@&tableD=%@&tableE=%@&tableF=%@&TYPE=%@", audio, automate, by, envelope, length, name, notes, output, patch_name, s_cmd, shape, table, table0, table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6, table7, table8, table9, tableA, tableB, tableC, tableD, tableE, tableF, type];
    [BackgroundLoader loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:website]]];
```

The output I get is:

```
AUDIOAUTOMATEBYENVELOPELENGTHNAMENOTESOUTPUTPATCH_NAMES_CMDSHAPETABLETABLE0...TABLEFthere has been a problem
```

Can anyone see why this code is not updating the table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your problem lies with these: `$...=strip_tags($_GET['...']); ` .. hmmmm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have fields named like `BY`, `TABLE`, `TYPE` which are reserved words. Use backquotes for these:

```
`BY` = '$by',
...

`TABLE` = '$table',
...

`TYPE` = '$type' ;" );
```

Comment: @yorksensei: See also other answers for the (standard) way to `INSERT INTO` a table using `VALUES` syntax. The `INSERT ... SET` syntax is used only by MySQL so it's better to use the other one just in case you ever need to change RDBMS (less changes in the code will be needed).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I will rewrite this as stated. Thanks again for your excellent help.

Answer (score 4):

you can use the insert set format for mysql queries

the problem can be found by adding this after your query

```
if (mysql_error()) {
   die (mysql_error());
}
```

that will give you an error message

at a guess i would say that the semi-colon at the end of the query will cause a problem, this is not required when called via php

also you should put backticks around the column names. you will probably find that TYPE is a reserved word, so at a bare minimum put backticks around `TYPE`

also your script is open to sql injection. try using $value = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['value']) to stop that from happening

Answer (score 1):

Insert is not used with SET following should do

```
INSERT INTO `noise` VALUES(
    $value,
    ....
)
```

EDIT:
If you need to specify field names use the following:

```
INSERT INTO `noise` 
(field1, field2, ....)
VALUES(
    $value1,
    $value2,
    ....
)
```

Comment: mysql allows insert set statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen `INSERT` ... `SET` used.  You could try the more usual `INSERT` .. `VALUES` syntax as follows:

```
INSERT INTO <table name> ( `FIELD1`, `FIELD2` )
VALUES ( VALUE1, VALUE2 )
```

As bumperbox suggests - it's probably failing because you're using a keyword as one of your field names.  Surround your field names with backticks (**`**) to avoid them being interpreted as keywords by MySQL.  e.g.:

```
`TYPE` = ...
```

Comment: mysql allows insert set statements http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html

Comment: @bumperbox - I wasn't aware of that - I'll edit my answer with that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are mixing numbers with strings and the strings have to be quoted. I have had lots of trouble with this and have switched back to using values syntax.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest ditching all of that and using prepared statements in combination with PDO.  Your code, as it stands, is vulnerable to a SQL-injection attack.